# VFP 9 - MySql Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, visual-foxpro

Connecting from VFP 9 To MySql

`lnTestForExisting=SQLEXEC(m.WorkingDatabase, "SELECT student_id, date_treated, where_treated, treatment, id AS CloudId ;
FROM medical WHERE school_id=?lcSchoolId AND downloaded_to_desktop!='Y'","StudentsMedFromServer")`

Works Fine Data comes down just like it should then when I go to send the update back to the server using this

```
lnGoodServerUpdate=SQLEXEC(m.WorkingDatabase,"UPDATE SET medical downloaded_to_desktop='Y' WHERE SchoolId=?ServerSchoolId and id=?lnCloudId")
```

Generates syntax error and says the error is near the Where clause - the value in ?ServerSchoolId is reported as _lati (and then it cuts off I assume the word is _latin)

TIA

Comment: `update table_name set` perhaps `update medical set downloaded_to_desktop='Y' ................`

Comment: That was it, thank you.   What a 'well duh' moment for me Thanks again.